# Why is a set function equivalent to its induced outer measure if it is countably monotone?

Tags: measure-theory

Denote Outer measure as $\mu^*(E)$ and a set function $\mu(E)$.

Define outer measure as the following:
μ*(E) = inf $\Sigma\mu(E_k)$ where $\{E_k\}$ cover E.

Why is a set function equivalent to its induced outer measure  if it is countably monotone?

Comment: What do you mean by "equivalent"?  Note that  any measure $\mu$ is countably monotone. Also, any outer measure is countably monotone.

Comment: The value is equivalent to that of the induced outer measure

Comment: A  countably monotone set function is NOT equivalent to its induced outer measure. Example: Consider the real interval $[0,1]$. Let $\Sigma=\{\emptyset, [0,1]\}$. It is easy to see that $\Sigma$ is a $\sigma$-algebra. Define $\mu$ on $\Sigma$ by $\mu(\emptyset)=0$ and $\mu([0,1])=1$. Note that $\mu$ is a measure and so countably monotone. The value of $\mu$ is defined for two sets only. However, $\mu^*$, the induced outer measure, is defined on $P([0,1])$. So the value of $\mu^*$ is defined for all subsets of $[0,1]$. In fact, $\mu^*(\emptyset)=0$ and $\mu^*(E)=1$ if $E\neq \emptyset$.

Comment: Okay, but the result I mentioned was stated in Royden's book. Maybe I missed a condition?

Comment: Can you give a more precise reference?  Where in Royden's book?

Comment: On a second read on your counterexample, I don't see a set function though. Seems you are saying measure and outer measure are defined on different domains which I agree.

Comment: In my counterexample both $\mu$ and $\mu^*$  are set functions. Actually, all measures and all outer measures are set functions.

Comment: I meant you don't have a general set function.

Comment: What do you mean by "general set function"? What is the definition of "general set function" you are using?

Comment: It is a mapping from a set to R. The domain can be any collection of subsets of $\Omega$. Using this definition, you can obtain an induced outer measures using the definition in the post.

Comment: So, all measures and all outer measures are general set functions. And, in my countereample, both $\mu$ and $\mu^*$ are  general set functions.

Comment: Yes but they are not equivalent according to this construction. The definition of outer measure is in the post. It is defined as an infimum.

Comment: Denote Outer measure as $\mu^*(E)$ and a set function $\mu(E)$.

Define outer measure as the following:
μ*(E) = inf $\Sigma\mu(E_k)$ where $\{E_k\}$ cover E.

Comment: By the way, the statement is from page 354 of Royden.

Comment: I have never said $\mu$ and $\mu^*$ in my counterexample were equivalent. In fact, my claim is precisely that they are NOT equivalent.

Comment: In my counterexample, $\mu$ is measure (and so a set function) and $\mu^*$ is the induced outer measure (by the same definition you presented). $\mu$  is defined for only two sets ($\emptyset$ and $[0,1]$) and  $\mu^*$ is defined for all sets in $P([0,1])$. They are NOT equivalent.

Comment: Ok. I have found the sentence in Royden's Book.  It is a commentary about the proof of Caratheodory extension theorem (Theorem 12).  It means a completely different thing.  Royden does NOT say "a set function equivalent to its induced outer measure if it is countably monotone". 

He says, **under the assumption of Caratheodory extension theorem (Theorem 12)** that "the countable monotonicity of $\mu$ is equivalent to the equality $\mu(E) = \mu^*( E)$, for all $E \in \mathcal{S}$".  It means that $\mu^*$ is an **extension** of $\mu$ if and only if $\mu$ is countably monotone.

Comment: The equivalence is NOT between $\mu$ and $\mu^*$. The equivalence is  between the condition that $\mu$ be countably monotone and the condition that $\mu^*$ be an extension of $\mu$.

Comment: The first sentence in the paragraph before the remark on page 354 states what I claimed.

Comment: The first line in the paragraph before the remark on page 354 is "Clearly $\mu( E) = \mu^*( E)$ for each set $E \in \mathcal{S}$  if and only if $\mu$ is countable monotone".  It states that $\mu^*$ is an **extension** of $\mu$ if and only if  $\mu$ is countable monotone.  The equivalence is NOT between $\mu$  and $\mu^*$. The equivalence is between the condition of $\mu^*$ being an extension of $\mu$ and the condition of $\mu$ being countable monotone. It very different from your claim.

Comment: I was saying "a set function equivalent to its induced outer measure if it is countably monotone". I don't see how this is different from the book.

Comment: Your claim is: " IF  $\mu$ is countable monotone THEN $\mu$ and $\mu^*$  are equivalent ".  First point : $\mu^*$ is an extension of $\mu$. The relationship "A is an extension of B" is not symmetric and can not be called an equivalence.  So the first correction to you claim would be to say   " IF  $\mu$ is countable monotone THEN $\mu^*$ is an extension of $\mu$".  Then it is correct. But Royden says more. He says: " $\mu$ is countable monotone IF AND ONLY IF $\mu^*$ is an extension of $\mu$".  Now we have an equivalence, but a logical equivalence between two conditions.

Comment: What is your definition of "A is an extension of B"?

Comment: "$A$is an extension of $B$"  means  that If $B$ is defined on $x$ then $A$ is defined on $x$ and $A(x)=B(x)$.  By the way, that is the standard meaning of "$A$is an extension of $B$"in mathematics.

Comment: I see. I guess I misunderstood it. So is it correct to say that "μ(E)=μ∗(E) for each set E∈S" means for every E from S,  μ is defined on E by definition and we set the value of μ*(E) to be equal to μ(E)? Thus, μ∗ is an extension μ?

Comment: Correct.  Then if you say  "IF $\mu$ is countable monotone THEN $\mu^∗$ is an extension of $\mu$", you are correct.  And Royden states even more: " $\mu$ is countable monotone IF AND ONLY IF $\mu^∗$ is an extension of $\mu$".

Comment: I see. Seems like you already have the answer to the question. Can you put it in an answer instead of comment? I will then mark the question as solved! Thanks for explanation!